# Вертикальное выравнивание по центру bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Друзья, пример проблемы навел кодом в codepen

Мне необходимо разместить белую кнопку, которая справа по центру (по вертикали). Испробовал уже много классов из бутстрапа, кнопке назначал display: inline, всеравно разместить кнопку по центру не получается. В данный момент она размещена вверху по вертикали.

Обьясните пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Вот ссылка:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/whoisdt-the-styleful/pen/XYvoJv)

```
<section class="conversion-screen">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9 conversion-text">
                <h4>Бесплатный трансфер</h4>
                <p>Наш хостел осуществляет бесплатный трансфер от жд/автовокзала в случае гарантированного бронирования с сайта 
                    на сумму более 1000 руб, а также с аэропорта.  Стоимость гарантированного бронирования для трансфера с аэропорта 4000 руб.
                </p>
                <p class="lighten">Услуга беслплатного трансфера предоставляется при провозе багажа в багажнике легкового автомобиля.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-auto col-2 text-right align-middle">
                <div class="action-button white-button">Бронировать</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Обьясните пожалуйста в чем проблема?
>   В этом `<div class="row">`

```css
.conversion-screen {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(103.15deg, #0584A6 0%, #3386C6 100%);
  padding: 16px 0px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}

p.lighten {
  margin-top: 16px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.action-button {
  min-width: 136px;
  height: 32px;
  background: linear-gradient(103.15deg, #0584A6 0%, #3386C6 100%);
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  text-align: center;
}

.white-button {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="conversion-screen">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-9 conversion-text">
        <h4>Бесплатный трансфер</h4>
        <p>Наш хостел осуществляет бесплатный трансфер от жд/автовокзала в случае гарантированного бронирования с сайта на сумму более 1000 руб, а также с аэропорта. Стоимость гарантированного бронирования для трансфера с аэропорта 4000 руб.
        </p>
        <p class="lighten">Услуга беслплатного трансфера предоставляется при провозе багажа в багажнике легкового автомобиля.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ml-auto col-2 text-right align-middle">
        <div class="action-button white-button">Бронировать</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: я просто применял класс align-middle. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: не за что, хорошего дня :)